# How do I get the data I imported using IMPORTRANGE to tie to the manually entered data in my sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, importrange

I have two columns I need to import into a target sheet that will auto-update when they are changed in the source. I also have custom, manually entered data in the target sheet that describes the data imported using `IMPORTRANGE`. If someone inserts a new row in the source sheet, it will add a new row to the imported columns, but that will throw off the alignment of the data in the rows of other columns I've manually entered in the target sheet. How can I associate the `IMPORTRANGE` rows with the data in rows of the other columns so a new row inserted into the source sheet inserts a new row in all columns of the target sheet?

I haven't found anything to try yet

```
=importrange("sourcedoc/edit","SourceSheetG2:G")
```

When data is entered into the source sheet, it updates the target sheet but throws off the alignment of the other data. The expected output is that, if someone adds a new row in the source, it adds a new row to all columns in the target sheet.

Answer (score 1):

that's not possible. you will need to rethink your approach and implement some supporting system like IDs. then you can use **`VLOOKUP`** to match both datasets based on ID